# Add image to listview from Gallery in Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is currently what I have achived,

[image]

```
@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Scaffold([![enter image description here][1]][1]
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: GestureDetector(
      child: Image.asset('graphics/back_arrow.png'),
      onTap: () {
        Get.back();
      },
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Text(
      'Ask The Internet',
      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("graphics/login.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: _height * 0.15,
        ),
        Container(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 64, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
          height: _height * 0.85,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(64),
              topRight: Radius.circular(64),
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Ask The Internet',
                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: loginPageTitleColor),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.04,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Upload Content for UP',
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: askInternetPageTitleColor),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.01,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Image.asset('graphics/add.png'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _pickImages();
                      },
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Image.asset('graphics/divider.png')),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.04,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Upload Content for DOWN',
                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: askInternetPageTitleColor),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.01,
                ),
                Image.asset('graphics/add.png'),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Image.asset('graphics/divider.png')),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.06,
                ),
                TextFieldInput(
                  titleText: 'Text up to 140 characters',
                  hintText: 'Enter Question',
                  inputType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  textEditingController: controller.questionController,
                  titleTextStyle: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      color: editProfivePageTitleColor),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.04,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'Ask The Community',
                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: loginPageTitleColor),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.04,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select The Community',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black38),
                ),
                Obx(
                  () => DropdownButton<CommunityItem>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: controller.item.value,
                    items:
                        controller.communityRows.map((CommunityItem value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<CommunityItem>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value!.name!),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      controller.item.value = value!;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.04,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      height: 55,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(4.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.black,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage("graphics/btn.png"),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Save",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ) // button text

                      ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("you clicked me");
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

I want when user click on plus icon he can add images from gallery, just like this.

I tried to use Listview builder but it was not prefect.
[image]